# Regular expression to reformat blocks of integers (magic squares)

Tags: regex

## The regex requirement

I have a large file containing magic squares, in groups of four separated by spaces:

```
 2 16  1 15    10  5 12  7     9  3 14  8    13  6 11  4
14  9  8  3     3  9  8 14     5 10  7 12    12 10  7  5
11  4 13  6     6  4 13 11    16 15  2  1     1 15  2 16
 7  5 12 10    15 16  1  2     4  6 11 13     8  3 14  9
```

Eventually I want to find and reformat these groups so each separate magic square appear separately like this:

```
 2 16  1 15
14  9  8  3
11  4 13  6
 7  5 12 10

10  5 12  7
 3  9  8 14
 6  4 13 11
15 16  1  2

 9  3 14  8
 5 10  7 12
16 15  2  1
 4  6 11 13

13  6 11  4
12 10  7  5
 1 15  2 16
 8  3 14  9
```

### Finding each group of four digits

To start, I have a Regex that finds all groups of four numbers, but this only gives me the 16 matches I need *if* I specify each integer preceded by 0-2 spaces:

```
(( {0,2}\d{1,2}){4}).*?
```

([saved version on Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3bfdl))

### The problem with the solution

I want to capture only zero or one space preceding the integers at the start of each column, but **not** the four that separate each block of 16.

## The bigger problem

Then I need to capture each of the 16 groups of four integers and reformat them from as captured group

```
\1\5\9\13\n\n
```

to give:

```
 2 16  1 15
14  9  8  3
11  4 13  6
 7  5 12 10
```

but my regex so far captures everything. How do I separate the capture groups to achieve this?

Comment: To be honest, I think a regexp is not the proper way to tackle this problem. Regular expressions are made for matching & searching, **not** transforming input, of which this is clearly an example. Even a simple shell script could do this better/quicker than a regexp.

Comment: I did think of awk or sed. It's a few years since I used awk but it ripped through transforming a string in a huge (thousands of files) website the last time I used it. So you're probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a scripting language like python

Here's my solution. Works pretty well I think.

```
squares = []
row_counter = 0
four = None
with open('magic-squares.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        numbers = row.split()
        if numbers:
            if row_counter == 0:
                if four:
                    squares += four
                four = [[],[],[],[]]
            for i in range(4):
                four[i] += numbers[i*4:i*4+4]
            row_counter += 1
            row_counter %= 4

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(' '.join(square) for square in squares))

with open('output2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(
        '\n\n'.join(
            '\n'.join(
                ''.join(
                    ["{:<2} ".format(item) for item in square[i*4:(i+1)*4]]
                ) for i in range(4)
            ) for square in squares
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Graeme - I'll try this out tonight.

Comment: finally got around to running this and it works nicely. Just had to add a duplicate of the last four lines to extract the last four squares.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you something like this:

```
(( {0,2}?\d{1,2}){4}) +(( {0,2}?\d{1,2}){4}) +(( {0,2}?\d{1,2}){4}) +(( {0,2}?\d{1,2}){4})
```

that you can have this results:

```
$1

 2 16  1 15
14  9  8  3
11  4 13  6
 7  5 12 10

$3

10  5 12  7
3  9  8 14
6  4 13 11
15 16  1  2

$5
...

$7
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but - like my original attempt - this gets single integers every other find, so I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that regex is not good choice for that job but it is possible. To match for example all four squares at once, and extract them in order you want, you can use this ridiculously long regex:

```
^((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+(.+)\n((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+(.+)\n((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+(.+)\n\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)\s+((?:\s{0,2}\d+)+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2zX7/1)

and then use all groups from $1 to $16 to get squares. However I am not sure is it useful in another way than regex exercise.

Comment: This ridiculously long regex actually did the job in a blink in my texteditor. Thanks for the demo, too.